# How to use array modifier with units?

Tags: modifiers, units

Pretty new to Blender, I'm trying to learn how to make a studded wall.

How do I use the array modifier to use imperial units? For example, I would like to create a stud, and have them spaced 16 inches on center a set distance.

Thank you much!

**Sorry if this is a duplicate, I asked this question yesterday but it was closed, so I'm asking again.**

Comment: Hi. Please address the issues with the original question by using the 'edit' link below it. Once the issues have been addressed it will enter a review queue to see if it should be re-opened. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my fault. I did edit it, but I had noticed it was still [closed] So I wasn't sure if that was still a valid question.